# DLL not being updated when building my solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

Strange situation.

inside a solution I have several projects. One of them is called Common, other is a web project (not a web application) called Internal.

Internal has a reference to Common, so every time I build the application, the common DLL is copied to the bin folder on the Internal website.

If I change a line of code on a class on the Common project and rebuilt it the DLL isn't updated on the Internal bin folder (even If I rebuild the internal) resulting in running the OLD code of the Common (If I have a breakpoint on Common, it show a warning saying that the code differs from the original and wont run). The only way I manage to solve it is manually deleting the Common DLL on Internal and then rebuilding.

My question is, how can I avoid it? How can the dll always be the same version on Internal?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I'm not certain here, but if you go to internal, view the references where Common is referenced and go to properties on it. Copy Local should be set to True. I think that this is it but I'm no expert so I'm not sure.

Comment: When you did an 'Add Reference' did you select the DLL through 'Browse' or through 'Projects'? EDIT: Just saw comment above, that is where i was going next!

Comment: Have you tried setting the Copy To Output Directory to "Copy Always" for that dll?

Comment: a trivial clue: have you tried rebuilding all the solution, using build\rebuild solution menu command?

Comment: It's worth checking how you build the DLL too. F5 builds to the Debug folder and F6 to the Release folder.

Comment: Try setting the build output to diagnostic. Sometimes it's very helpful.

Comment: hi, thanks for all the replies. @ADC I tried, didn't work, I had to manually delete the DLL. Johnie and Ingo, I don't have access to that "references" folder under the project to check the proprieties you suggested (probably because it is a old web site, not web application) I can only see the references by right clicking the project and choosing "properties". Dave I think you were right, I probably added the reference to the DLL, I removed and added it again to the project and it seems to be working. If you add your suggestion as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: @Diego have done as you asked, answer ready for marking. Glad you got your asseblies working ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested by OP:

Try removing the reference and adding again though the 'Projects' option on the 'Add Reference' dialog. This should set up the DLL to be refreshed when it is rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

**One** of possible straightforward solutions could be the simple use of `PostBuildEvent` where you put batch-code that on successful build **always** copies files you need.

The bad about this that you increase your compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using third party dll which has been developed been higher version VS2013/vs2015 (i.e .NEt 4.5 , 4.6 , 4.6.2) then it will not work properly in VS2010
Answer: Convert your project to VS2015 to resolve issue or install .NET 4.6.2 and user VS2013 and change framework to latest